Why does asynchronous invocation eliminate stack dives?
I was reading Stephen Toub's blog post on How Async/Await Really Works in C#. In the article he describes how this code (posted below) would cause a stack overflow to occur because the BeginRead method would complete synchronously and invoke the AsyncCallback lambda, which would invoke BeginRead again etc...
He then provides possible solutions to this problem, one of which is:

Don’t allow the AsyncCallback to be invoked synchronously. If it’s always invoked asynchronously, even if the operation completes synchronously, then the risk of stack dives goes away. But so too does performance, because operations that complete synchronously (or so quickly that they’re observably indistinguishable) are very common, and forcing each of those to queue its callback adds measurable overhead.

This isn't obvious to me. So my question is:
Why would asynchronous invocation of the callback prevent stack dives?
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

using Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0));
listener.Listen();

using Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(listener.LocalEndPoint!);

using Socket server = listener.Accept();
_ = server.SendAsync(new byte[100_000]);

var mres = new ManualResetEventSlim();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

var stream = new NetworkStream(client);

void ReadAgain()
{
    stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 1, iar =>
    {
        if (stream.EndRead(iar) != 0)
        {
            ReadAgain(); // uh oh!
        }
        else
        {
            mres.Set();
        }
    }, null);
};
ReadAgain();

mres.Wait();


I think you're misunderstanding the essential point that synchronous invocation of this asynchronous method is what can result in a stack dive / stack overflow. The method in question is asynchronous. Whenever it's called asynchronously, the caller finishes it's routine and is ultimately disposed; on a following event loop cycle the asynchronous method actually executes. When it's called synchronously it results in recursive behavior, which will continue to consume the stack until an overflow occurs or the frame unwinds.

Most often stack dives occur because the same code is recursively called.  Stack dives can also occur when an exception causes another exception to occur.  Another reason for stack dives is when large amount of data is put onto the stack.  So I'm not sure what Stephen's reasoning is sound.  Stephen may be correct, but his reasoning is not.  I like hOr53 explanation.

@jdweng well I can see pretty clearly how the 100,000 recursive calls to ReadAgain() would cause the stack to overflow. Just try running the code yourself.

I'm not sure how to reply.  I agree your code is recursively calling itself over and over again.  So for every read you are pushing another call onto the stack and using a lot of memory.  The code is not in an endless loop.  Eventually you will read the EOF and stop.  So this is NOT a stack dive.  It is poor coding.  if you have enough memory then the code will run.  Stephen does not address this issue in his posting.  I also do not think the other answers below really answers your question.

@jdweng it is synthetic code for demo purposes. With proper read requesting size (other than 1 in code sample) network stack buffer is going to be exhausted, and at some point of time there would no data be accessible in the buffer, and here we have to wait, callback will be invoked asynchronously, in other thread. With 1 read size it is guaranteed that there always will be work for CPU to do in current thread.

@Ryan : I know.  Your comment isn't addressing the OPs question.

Note that Stephen is discussing the internal implementation of stream.BeginRead, providing the ReadAgain function as an example of how the caller of this function might trigger a stack overflow. And how you could implement stream.BeginRead to balance speed and stack usage. Then of course how async/await completely avoids this pitfall.

First some terminology. Asynchronous invocation is a fancy way of saying that the invocation is offloaded to the ThreadPool. Instead of invoking something right now on the current thread, we request that a thread owned by the ThreadPool will invoke it as soon as possible. Since the current thread won't have to invoke it, it will be free to do other things, like serve the UI message loop. Or it may have nothing else to do, in which case it might return itself as an available worker to the ThreadPool, or simply terminate.
Let's see an example of a stack dive that causes a StackOverflowException:
public void DoSomething()
{
    DoSomething();
}

This is obviously an infinite recursion, so it is destined to crash the process. Let's fix it:
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync());
}

The Task.Run invokes an action on the ThreadPool, and returns a Task that represents the completion of the invocation.
Now each subsequent recursion is performed on a ThreadPool thread, which is likely to be a different thread than the previous recursion. But it can also be the same thread if the ThreadPool is running low on threads, and the same thread returns to the ThreadPool and is assigned the scheduled work, starting with a clean stack every time.

To understand the "stack dives" we need to acknowledge that asynchronous operations can complete asynchronously as well as synchronously.
What synchronously means here is without the need to offload the completion of the work to other threads (or register for IO completion events with the OS).
Or put simply, our execution path stayed on the same thread that initiated the asynchronous work.
The (thread) stack helps us keep track of the execution path. The longer we stay on this execution path and the more stops we make, the larger the stack grows (i.e. stack dives). The key point in the example that it's unfortunately hidden is that BEFORE BeginRead() returns (and frees stack space) it calls the registered callback. So the execution path becomes something like this:
ReadAgain -> BeginRead -> Callback -> ReadAgain -> BeginRead....
Now that we get that, I think your question

Why would asynchronous invocation of the callback prevent stack dives?

misrepresents the point that Stephen Toub makes. We need to prevent synchronous invocation (not initiate asynchronous invocation) to stop the stack dive.
This is his solution to the problem:
IAsyncResult ar = handler.BeginDoStuff(arg, iar => {
    if (!iar.CompletedSynchronously) {
        try {
            Handler handler = (Handler)iar.AsyncState!;
            int i = handler.EndDoStuff(iar);
            Use(i);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            ... // handle exceptions from EndDoStuff and Use
            }
    }
}, handler);
if (ar.CompletedSynchronously) {
    int i = handler.EndDoStuff(ar);
    Use(i);
}

So how would that help us? In the chain (call stack) that we already had
ReadAgain -> BeginRead -> Callback
we have a check in the Callback (!iar.CompletedSynchronously). This is false because we have completed synchronously. So the code block is not executed and we return from the Callback. At this point we are back in BeginRead. We return from it as well and we are back in the ReadAgain method. So now our call stack is just
ReadAgain
And we do the continuation work in the ReadAgain method.
if (ar.CompletedSynchronously) {
    int i = handler.EndDoStuff(ar);
    Use(i);
}

So, by preventing the callback from engaging in synchronous work by just returning from it, we have saved ourselves stack space.
